# How do I cut off the text view after 20 characters?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextviewdelegate

I am trying to limit the number of characters inside the text view to 20. After 20 it should instead have "...". The function is not firing and I am setting the delegate correctly.

Animal class

```
cell.pn.text = np[indexPath.row]
cell.pn.selectable = false
cell.pn.delegate = self
```

Extension of Animal class

```
extension Animal : UITextViewDelegate{
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    return textView.text.characters.count + (text.characters.count - range.length) <= 20
    }
}
```

Comment: try changing <=75 to <= 20

Comment: Originally I wanted 75, but forgot to change it, when I breakpoint it nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
            if displayName.characters.count > 20 {
                displayName = (displayName as NSString).substringToIndex(20)
                displayName.appendContentsOf("...")
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let text = textField.text
        let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
        return newLength <= 20
    }
```

Comment: Does not work, 1) when I break point on the function nothing happens, 2) I am using a text view not a text field